# Window Transparency with Java

Tags: 14.04, unity, java

I'm using a java application that relies heavily on window transparency it to work properly (windows apparently fade on top of each other to make them cross over each other). On Windows it works just fine, but on Ubuntu, none of the transparency works correctly, and all of the windows fade to white as if they have no alpha value. Is there any work around with Ubuntu to allow Java to use transparent windows?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could mention which version of Java you're using. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with Oracle Java 8. To test transparent window handling, I downloaded, compiled, and ran Oracle's [shaped translucent window demo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/misc/ShapedWindowDemoProject/src/misc/ShapedWindowDemo.java):

```
$ mkdir misc
$ cd misc
$ wget -q https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/misc/ShapedWindowDemoProject/src/misc/ShapedWindowDemo.java
$ javac ShapedWindowDemo.java 
$ cd ..
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
$ java misc.ShapedWindowDemo
```

A transparent window was successfully created, as the screenshot shows:

[image: Transparent window]

So my first suggestion would be to try the program with Oracle Java 8, if you haven't already done so.